# Firebase Multiple Admin Types

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

In the product I am developing (using ReactJS and Firebase Auth with Firestore), I need to set up the following account types:

Super Admin 
Content Admin
User Admin

Currently, I have a form that once a users email is entered, it will give an "admin" token to the user with that email address.

What's the best way I could do this with the 3 different admin types?

I have included the code that sets the Admin token.

**AddAdmin.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './AddAdmin.scss'
const firebase = require("firebase");

class AddAdmin extends Component {
    state = {
      superAdminEmail: ''
    }
  
    updateAdminEmail = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        adminEmail: e.target.value
      })
    }
  
    addAdmin = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const addAdminRole = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addAdminRole');
      addAdminRole({email: this.state.adminEmail})
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result);
          })
    }
  
    render() {
      return (
          <div className = "AddAdminForm">
              <form className = "admin-actions" onSubmit={this.addAdmin}>
                  <input type = "email" placeholder = "User email" id = "admin-email" value={this.state.adminEmail} onChange={this.updateAdminEmail} required/>
                  <button type="submit"> Make Admin </button>
              </form>
          </div>
        
      )
    }
  }
export default AddAdmin
```

**Index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addAdminRole = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // get user and add admin custom claim
  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then(user => {
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
      admin: true
    })
  }).then(() => {
    return {
      message: `Success! ${data.email} has been made an admin.`
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    return err;
  });
});
```

Comment: You may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which shows how to create an Admin module for managing Firebase users access and roles.

Comment: Your code lets anyone assign themsevles admin status simply by invoking the function.  It's not secure.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the info, my expertise is frontend and this is my first time tackling the backend side of things. How would you suggest I make it more secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to extend your logic by introducing radio buttons to select the role and then, on submit, it will call a specific handler (addAdmin / addSuperAdmin / addContextAdmin) on form submit.

If the radio btn for User Admin is selected, call `addAdmin` which inturn calls `addAdminRole` cloud function.

Similarly, you can introduce other two cloud functions (in index.js) -> `addSuperAdminRole` and `addContextAdminRole`.

Then call the related handler according to the radio buttons selected.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help. I'll give that a shot tomorrow and get back to you!